# How to register class in YAML for gremlin serializer - Class is not registered: org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph

Tags: hbase, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I get the following error when creating a new graph using JanusGraph ConfiguredGraphFactory().

```
179262 [gremlin-server-session-1] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.MessageSerializer  - Response [ResponseMessage{requestId=9cdb34da-2033-4d08-9636-724743f0b798, status=ResponseStatus{code=SUCCESS, message='', attributes={}}, result=ResponseResult{data=[standardjanusgraph[hbase:[127.0.0.1]]], meta={}}}] could not be serialized by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV1d0.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph
Note: To register this class use:     kryo.register(org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.class);
```

This happen when I run this command from gremlin client

```
ConfiguredGraphFactory.create("graph");
```

May I know how should I register org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph in YAML?

The gremlin-server.yaml is defined as followed. I believe I should add something in the serializers section?

```
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.janusgraph.channelizers.JanusGraphWebSocketChannelizer
graphManager: org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager
graphs: {
  ConfigurationManagementGraph: conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-hbase-configurationgraph.properties
}
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    plugins: { org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin: {},
           org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {},
           org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.jsr223.TinkerGraphGremlinPlugin: {},
           org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin: {classImports: [java.lang.Math], methodImports: [java.lang.Math#*]},
           org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: []}}}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  # Older serialization versions for backwards compatibility:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0, config: {ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0,     config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  gangliaReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000, addressingMode: MULTICAST},
  graphiteReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000}}
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a server running with the config you provided, you now want to connect to it from a groovy script. That's where I had the same problem.
The solution was the following:

```
cluster = Cluster.open("../conf/remote.yaml")
client = cluster.connect()
client.init()
client.submit('kryo.register(org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.class)\n'+
              'ConfiguredGraphFactory.open("mygraph")')
GraphTraversalSource g = EmptyGraph.instance().traversal().withRemote(
                           DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "mygraph_traversal"))
```

This works without the gremlin console, so you can directly compile and execute this groovy script (given the necessary dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 has been deprecated.
Use GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1

```
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```